# choose rows where 10 columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get a rows using one string, but this string is used to validate more than 1 column, exactly 5, for example

```
-----------------------------------------------
|  id  |  code  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  01  | Number |  5  |  7  |  10 |  21 |  1  |
|  02  | String |  v  |  q  |  s  |  f  |  w  |
|      |        |     |     |     |     |     |
|      |        |     |     |     |     |     |
|      |        |     |     |     |     |     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want to make SELECT mysqli where using 5 columns ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) if i use looping method, it will waste a lot of time

i have tried the problem with this code

```
$value = "q";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
  $cek = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table where $x='$value' and id='02'")
  if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 1) {
    echo "success";
  } else {
    echo "fail";
  }
}
```

I use this code successfully, but the process is too long

is there an easier and more practical way to overcome this problem? thank you

Comment: *is there an easier and more practical way to overcome this problem?* - Design your database according to commonly accepted principles and this could be a simple select.

Comment: ```WHERE `1` = '$value' OR `2` = '$value' OR ...```…?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, your database design is sub-optimal. You may want to reconsider and change it. Also, having column names be `1`, `2`, etc. is a *very* bad idea.  At least have them start with a letter.  Better yet, give them some reasonable names indicating what data those columns actually contain.

Now, assuming you figured out what your column names should really be, you can use a simple `IN` operator to get your data.  The usual/common way of using it is

```
WHERE some_column IN ('value1', 'value2', ...)
```

Yet, there's nothing preventing you from using it the other way around:

```
WHERE 'some_value' IN (column1, column2, ...)
```

This way, your SQL statement becomes something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE '$value' IN (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
AND id='02'
```

Now, if you have your column names in an array, you can do it this way:

```
$testColumns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'];
$value = "q";

$inColumns = implode(',', $testColumns);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$value' IN ($inColumns) AND id='02'";
$cek = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

**UPDATE:** If your column names are non-standard, e.g. the aforementioned `1`, `2`, etc., or have spaces in them, then simple `implode` will not work, because you need to back-quote each column name.  In that case, you would need something like this:

```
$inColumns = implode(',', array_map(function($c) { return "`$c`"; }, $columns));
```